Input bulk cap of a flyback converter
Doing calculation for input bulk capacitor of a flyback converter. Have attached my calcultions.
Also used Ti calculator.
Why am I getting different values? What am I doing wrong? And how to do the calculation for a clc filter/ pi filter? Can't seem to find any good resource for that,  I have been following this video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OhPVDhIDCjc




rachit juthani - Hi, At least one of those images seems to have come from elsewhere. To comply with the site rule on referencing, details of the original source of copied / adapted material must be provided by you, next to each copied / adapted item. If the original source is online & public, please [edit] the question & add the webpage/video/etc. name & its link (URL) (e.g. website name + video title + its URL). (Doesn't apply here but if the source is offline (e.g. book or private intranet) then give full source details e.g. title, author, page, publisher, edition.)

I did not checked thoroughly but the first thing I noticed was that the $V_{min}$ and $V_{bulk,min}$ used in the refs you shared are not the same thing as your $V_{min}$ in your calculations.

My input is 60 to 300vAC , This calculation is for when input is 60vac, The video is for some other input voltage,

The graph and equations are coming from chapter 6 of my book on power supplies and no credits are given. Have a look at this PDF I posted years ago.
